# How to stop the RUN CODE automatically in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python

update: the problem was with my vs code terminal and its fixed.

I know that `ctrl` + `alt` + `M` stops the code, but for example, when I run something like this in Visual Studio Code it doesn't stop automatically.

```py
def login(y):
        x = input('Hi. what\'s your name? %s.\nHi %s ' % (y, y))
        return x

print(login('sajjad'))
```

Is there any solution to stop the code automatically? I know there is there are some problems with my script but that's not the point. The point is to stop the code after 'run code'.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `ctrl`+`shift`+ `M` You can try `ctrl`+`D` or `ctrl`+`Z`, but I think it not stopping automatically has something to do with your pc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstanding your script. As usual, the code should exit when there is no more action or function calling. In your case, your function return `x`, which is `input` call, and definitely it will keep running until you input something.